# Necesito imprimir el nombre del usuario en el drawernavigation pero el dato esta en el state como accedo a el?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Necesito imprimir el nombre de un usuario en la parte del drawer navigation pero los datos los tengo guardados en el state pero no se como acceder a ellos ya probe pasandole props y pasando el argumento pero todavia no consigo nada.

El problema es que esta todo en un .js aqui les adjunto mi codigo

Aqui es donde tengo guardado el dato

```
  export default class index extends Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state={
     uid:'',
     email:'',
     Nombre:''
  }
 }
```

Y aqui esta mi declaracion del drawernavigation

```
const RootDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
Home:{screen: Home},
Perfil:{screen: Perfil},
Cursos:{screen:Cursos}

},{
  drawerBackgroundColor:'#F64747',

  contentOptions:{
    activeTintColor: 'black',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    inactiveTintColor :'white'
  },

  contentComponent: (props) => (
       <Container>
        <View style={styles.drawerHeader}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('./../images/material-design-4k.jpg.png')}  style={{flex:1}}>   
           <Body>
        <Image
          style={styles.drawerImage}
           source={require('./../images/user.png')} />
        <Text style={styles.texto}>
        </Text>
         AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO IMPRIMIR EL DATO 
        <Text  style={styles.texto}>
          Correo
        </Text>
        </Body>
      </ImageBackground>
      </View>
      <Content>

        <DrawerItems {...props} />
      </Content>

    </Container>

  )
})
```

Comment: Podrias dar mas detalle de la arquitectura? Utizas Redux? En que momento tienes seteado en el state del componente index el Nombre? Lo tipico en estas situaciones es si utilizas redux es tomar de un reductor (llamemosle userReducer) el nombre de usuario. Cuando utilizas redux tu componente debes bindearlo al estado y a las acciones. Si no utilizas redux tendras que componerte de index y tomar el nombre de alli. Te dejo como respuesta una implementacion con redux.

Answer (score 0):

Esa información de sessión la puedes obtener tanto almacenandola en localstorage o si utilizas alguna arquitectura como Redux tomandola del estado global.

A continuación un ejemplo de como lograrlo con redux.

en tus userActions,js:

```
  export const login = (loginData) =>
        (dispatch, getState, restApi) =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                restApi(null)
                    .then((client) => {
                        client.apis.user.userLogin({loginData: loginData})
                            .then(response => {
                                return resolve(dispatch(setAuthorizationData({
                                    isLoggedIn: true,
                                    authorizationData: response.obj.responseContent
                                })));
                            })
                    })
            );
```

Esa funcion dispacha una accion que modifica el state de Redux (setAuthorizationData)

```
const setAuthorizationData = (data) => ({
    type: AUTHORIZATION,
    data
});
```

Dicha accion es interceptada por un reducer:

```
const authorizationReducer = createReducer(initialState,
    {

        [AUTHORIZATION](state, action) {
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: action.data.isLoggedIn,
                authorizationData: action.data.authorizationData,
            };
        },


    });

export default authorizationReducer;
```

Y finalmente tienes tu container bindeado al state de redux, por lo cual puedes acceder mediante props a esos datos luego de cargados. Fijate que accedo a **this.props.accountData.nombre** desde el container por el hecho de estar bindeado al state de redux.

```
class SideBar extends Component {

    render = () =>
     <Container>
        <View style={styles.drawerHeader}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('./../images/material-design-4k.jpg.png')}  style={{flex:1}}>   
           <Body>
        <Image
          style={styles.drawerImage}
           source={require('./../images/user.png')} />
        <Text style={styles.texto}>
        </Text>
        {this.props.accountData.nombre}
        <Text  style={styles.texto}>
          Correo
        </Text>
        </Body>
      </ImageBackground>
      </View>
      <Content>

        <DrawerItems {...props} />
      </Content>

    </Container>


}


export default connect(state => ({
    isLoggedIn: state.authorizationReducer.isLoggedIn,
    accountData: state.customerReducer.accountData,
    isAccountDataLoaded: state.accountReducer.isAccountDataLoaded,
}), dispatch => Binding.bindActionCreators(Binding.ActionCreators, dispatch))(SideBar);
```

Sobre como inicializar el store, bindear componentes a Redux e integrar esto con react-navigation te recomiendo que sigas estos tutoriales:

- Binding con redux: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react
- Integracion con react-navigation y redux: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

Ambas guias son bastante claras.